# Condtitional taxonomy terms (from different vocabularies) during content creation

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have existing content type using vocabularies for year, model name, manufacturer, etc. I want users to be able to create new content of a different content type where they would select model year to start and then be able to select from a list of model names tagged with that year. Even better, once they make that selection, it would be nice to have Drupal select manufacturer.

I've looked at [hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select), [SHS](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs), [entityreference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference), and others but can't seem to find something to work with terms in different vocabularies. Term relations looked promising but broke the taxonomy manager so I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.